# Какие из указанных операторов являются инициализацией, присвоением, объявлением, определением?

Tags: c++, переменные, инициализация

Запутался в терминах. Всё осложняется тем, что в разных книгах они описаны по-разному. Например, когда происходит инициализация, в момент объявления переменной или в момент первой передачи ей значения? Ниже список операторов. Что, по-вашему, представляет каждый из них?

```
int main(){
int x; //Инициализация без присвоения? Или всё-таки просто определение без инициализации? Хотя переменная, по идее, должна содержать некое "мусорное" значение, значит она инициализирована?
double y=2.1;
x=3;
}
```

Comment: Объявление переменной ,объвление переменной с явно указанным инциализатором, присваивание.

Comment: По порядку: объявление, объявление, объявление с инициализацией, присвоение.

Comment: А за что минус? Хороший вопрос, теоретические основы языка.

Comment: @VladD, вопрос не ко мне.

Comment: Зануднее и скучнее крестовика уткнувшегося в стандарт могут быть только два крестовика уткнувшихся в стандарт.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> `int x;`
>
> `double y=2.1;`

Это *declaration statement*

Пункт 3.1/2 стандарта гласит

> A declaration is a definition unless it declares a function without specifying the function’s body (8.4), it contains the extern specifier (7.1.1) or a linkage-specification 25 (7.5) and neither an initializer nor a function-body, it declares a static data member in a class definition (9.4), it is a class name declaration (9.1), it is an opaque-enum-declaration (7.2), or it is a typedef declaration (7.1.3), a using-declaration (7.3.3), a static_assert-declaration (Clause 7), an attribute-declaration (Clause 7), an empty-declaration (Clause 7), or a using-directive (7.3.4).

то есть в данном случае `int x;` и `double y=2.1;` это и объявление и определение.

т.к. переменные x и y объявлены внутри функции, то они "*automatic storage duration*", и к ним применяется правило

> Variables with automatic storage duration (3.7.3) are initialized each time their declaration-statement is executed. Variables with automatic storage duration declared in the block are destroyed on exit from the block

Разберем запись

```
int x ;
```

Обратимся к стандарту c++ (пункт 8.5/11)

> If **no initializer is specified** for an object, the object **is
>   default-initialized**; **if no initialization is performed, an object with
>   automatic** or dynamic **storage duration has indeterminate value.**

В нашем случае переменная будет default-initialized и будет иметь неопределенное значение.
Посмотрим в стандарте что такое *default-initialize* (пункт 8.5/6)

> To default-initialize an object of type T means:
>
> — if T is a (possibly cv-qualified) class type (Clause 9), the default constructor for T is called (and the initialization is ill-formed if T has no accessible default constructor);
>
> — if T is an array type, each element is default-initialized;
>
> **— otherwise, no initialization is performed.**

У нас переменная не классового типа и не массив, поэтому нас интересует только последний случай, из которого можно сделать вывод, что в данном случае инициализация не выполняется.

---

Разберем теперь строчку

```
double y=2.1;
```

Также обратимся к стандарту (пункт 8.5/13)

> **The form of initialization (using parentheses or =) is generally insignificant, but does matter when the initializer or the entity being initialized has a class type;** see below. A parenthesized initializer can be a list of expressions only when the entity being initialized has a class type.

То есть для double разницы между `double y=2.1;` и `double y(2.1);` фактически не будет. Далее (пункт 8.5/16)

> Otherwise, **the initial value of the object being initialized is the (possibly converted) value of the initializer expression.** Standard conversions (Clause 4) will be used, if necessary, to convert the initializer expression to the cv-unqualified version of the destination type; no user-defined conversions are considered. If the conversion cannot be done, the initialization is ill-formed.

Вывод: в данном случае double будет инициализирована значением 2.5. И это будет именно инициализация, а не присваивание.

---

```
x=3;
```

Это expression statement (пункт 6.2/1)

> Expression statements have the form
>
> `expression-statement:
>        expression_opt ;`
>
> **The expression is evaluated and its value is discarded.** The lvalue-to-rvalue (4.1), array-to-pointer (4.2), and function-to-pointer (4.3) standard conversions are not applied to the expression. All side effects from an expression statement are completed before the next statement is executed. An expression statement with the expression missing is called a null statement. [ Note: **Most statements are expression statements — usually assignments or function calls.** A null statement is useful to carry a label just before the } of a compound statement and to supply a null body to an iteration statement such as a while statement (6.5.1). — end note ]

Здесь у нас в expression_opt имеется assignment operator (пункт 5.17)

> 1. **The assignment operator (=)** and the compound assignment operators all **group right-to-left.** **All require a modifiable lvalue as their left operand and return an lvalue referring to the left operand.** The result in all cases is a bit-field if the left operand is a bit-field. In all cases, the assignment is sequenced after the value computation of the right and left operands, and before the value computation of the assignment expression.
> 2. **In simple assignment (=), the value of the expression replaces that of the object referred to by the left operand.**
> 3. **If the left operand is not of class type, the expression is implicitly converted (Clause 4) to the cv-unqualified type of the left operand.**

Вывод: в результате x станет равным 3 и "=" в данном случае будет означать именно "присваивание".

Comment: Отличный ответ.

Answer (score 5):

Я думаю, проблема в том, что в литературе по программированию термин инициализация часто используют в широком смысле, означающем, что некоторый объект должен получить допустимое значение.

Что касается в узком смысле, то есть в соответствии с терминологией, используемой в стандарте C++, то под инициализацией имеется в виду присвоение объекту значения в момент его создания (определения).

В первом параграфе раздела 8.5 Initializers стандарта C++ написано:

> 1 A declarator can specify an initial value for the identifier being
>   declared. The identifier designates a variable being initialized.

То есть декларатор (а этот термин используется лишь при объявлении переменных) может иметь начальное значение - инициализатор. И в этом случае говорят, что идентификатор, означающий переменную, инициализируется.

В этом фрагменте кода

```
int x; 
double y=2.1;
x=3;
```

переменная `x` была объявлена и определена, но не инициализирована. Значение этой переменной неопределенное и может даже не соответствовать любому допустимому значению для типа `int`. То есть в области памяти, выделенной под этот объект, может храниться любой "мусор".

Переменная `y` объявлена, определена и инициализирована значением 2.1.

Предложение

```
x=3;
```

называется предложением выражения, так как, фактически, это всего лишь выражение, записанное, как отдельное предложение. Это предложение содержит выражение присваивания: переменной `x`  присваивается значение 3.
Это предложение не является ни объявлением, ни определением переменной `x`, ни ее инициализацией, хотя в широком (не строгом) смысле слова порой говорят, что переменная была инициализирована, то есть ей в конце концов было присвоено некоторое допустимое значение.
Переменная `x` уже была объявлена и определена (то есть для объекта, который она обозначает, была выделена память) в самом начале фрагмента кода.

Имейте в виду, что определение является в то же время и объявлением. С другой стороны, объявление не всегда является определением. Самый наглядный пример - это объявление и определение функций. Например,

```
int f( int );
```

Это объявление функции с типом `int( int )`. То есть в этом предложении объявляется, что означает имя или идентификатор `f`.

Но это не есть определение функции, так как ее тело не определено, то есть не определено, что эта функция делает.

```
int f( int x ) { return x * x; }
```

Это объявление функции и в тоже время определение функции, так как здесь задано тело функции. Функция может быть объявлена несколько раз, но определена только один раз, если она не имеет спецификатора `inline`, то есть если она не является встроенной функцией.

Comment: «_в области памяти, выделенной под этот объект, может храниться любой "мусор"_» — а также trap representation

Comment: @VladD Так я об этом написал.

Comment: Ага, только сейчас заметил.

Comment: @VladD  А я что-то не понял, что за trap representation? Еще в книгах часто упоминается, что определение с инициализацией и простое присваивание хоть и похожи (испольхуется знак "="), но в корне различаются. Вот у Страуструпа, например: "These operations are so similar that C++ allows us to use the same notation (the =) for both":
 • Initialization (giving a variable its initial value)
• Assignment (giving a variable a new value)

Comment: @jumpjet67: Ну, на некоторых платформах (не на x86), неинициализированная память может содержать такое значение, при обращении к которому процесс вывалится. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/01/19/60162.aspx

Comment: @VladfromMoscow, пишешь правильно, но много.

Comment: @Антон Сазонов  Понял. Буду писать неправильно, но мало.:)

Comment: @VladfromMoscow, )) Уверен что ты понял то, что имел в виду я:)

Comment: @АнтонСазонов: а мне нравится, когда много и подробно.

Comment: @NickVolynkin, это похвально. Просто я считаю что любую мысль (в том числе и эту) можно выразить в более краткой форме. Не все ТС вникают в смысл написанного.

Comment: @АнтонСазонов: достоверно, кратко, понятно читателю, быстро, бесплатно — великоватый список требований. Если можете и хотите написать кратко, то пишите. Не думаю, что этого можно требовать от авторов.

Comment: @NickVolynkin, ничего "великоватого" не вижу. По поводу всего остального - у тебя свои принципы, а у меня свои. Я просто высказал своё мнение, и тебе его не навязываю.