# Вопрос по синтаксису куска кода

Tags: c++, синтаксис

Недавно наткнулся на такой кусок кода:

```
int n, razr(1);
    cin >> n;
    while (n!=0){
        if (n % 10 == 4) //неюзать7
            posit += razr;
        else 
            posit = posit + razr*2;
        n /= 10;
        razr *= 2;
```

Интересует конкретно строчка 1, можете объяснить что значит razr(1)?

Comment: Переменная типа `int`, инициалированная единицей.

Comment: Это инициализация переменной значением 1 в данном случае.

Comment: @VladD насколько часто используется подобная инициализация и есть ли существенная разница между использованием `razr(1)` или `razr = 1`?

Comment: @AndreiKhotko для классовых типов может быть разница, в зависимости от класса.

Answer (score 3):

Объявление переменной razr с инициализацией значением 1.
Можете написать

int n, razr = 1;

Для фундаментальных типов разницы не будет.

Вырезка из пункта 8.5/13 стандарта C++:

> The form of initialization (using parentheses or =) is generally insignificant, but does matter when the initializer or the entity being initialized has a class type;

Возможно, будет полезно: [Какие из указанных операторов являются инициализацией, присвоением, объявлением, определением?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/451151/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D1%8F%D0%B2%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%8E%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%B9-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D1%8F%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BC/)