# Что такое определение, объявление и инициализация переменной

Tags: c++, терминология, language-lawyer

Объясните пожалуйста доступно, что такое определение, объявление и инициализация **переменной**.
Как их отличать синтаксически. Что без чего можно делать, а что без чего нельзя. Прочитал уже несколько статей, теперь в голове только каша

Comment: Чтобы каши в голове не было, лучше читать учебники.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev посоветуй, пожалйста книгу, где можно об этом почитать

Comment: Приведённые раньше ответы неверные. Уже неоднократно поднималась эта тема на стеках. Вот пример правильного ответа https://stackoverflow.com/a/1410632. Также можно почитать тут https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/declarations, https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/definition. Ну и в Стандарте, разумеется https://eel.is/c++draft/.

Comment: @Slad, если вам нужны формально точные определения, тогда берите стандарт языка.

Comment: Чем вы занимаетесь? Что вам ближе чтоб объяснение было вам доступно.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/451151/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D1%8F%D0%B2%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%8E%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%B9-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D1%8F%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BC/

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Какие из указанных операторов являются инициализацией, присвоением, объявлением, определением?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/451151/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%83%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2-%d1%8f%d0%b2%d0%bb%d1%8f%d1%8e%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b5%d0%b9-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5%d0%bc-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8a%d1%8f%d0%b2%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5%d0%bc)

Answer (score 7):

*Нижеизложенное сильно упрощено. Здесь не преследуется цель рассказать подробно все нюансы - для этого лучше почитать Стандарт языка.*

Объявление (declaration) переменной информирует компилятор о том, что где-то, возможно, в другой единице трансляции (очень грубо, в другом cpp-файле) выделено `sizeof` *байт* под хранение переменной такого-то типа с таким-то именем. Деклараций можно писать сколько угодно в разных блоках кода, по одной на блок.

Определение (definition) переменной информирует тот же компилятор о том, что память под переменную нужно взять прямо в этом месте, где написано данное определение. Именно в этой единице трансляции. Определение на всю программу может быть одно и только одно.

Этими процессами управляют квалификаторы `static`, `extern`, `thread_local` и некоторые другие.

Чаще всего, происходят одновременно объявление и определение, например

```
int a; // вне функций - заставит компилятор создать глобальную переменную.

{
   int a;  //в блоке кода - переменная будет существовать до конца блока, а память будет выделена на стеке
}
```

Примером чисто объявления идентификатора будет объявление его со спецификатором `static` внутри структуры:

```
struct A
{
    static int a;    // объявление A::a
};
```

Никакая память на данный момент не выделена, но компилятор теперь знает, что у него такое есть. Для использования этого поля необходимо прежде определить его вне структуры:

```
int A::a;           // определение A::a

int b = A::a;       // теперь можно
```

Использование ключевого слова `extern`, которое как раз говорит компилятору, что переменная объявлена где-то в другой единице трансляции

```
 //alpha.cpp
 int a;

 //beta.cpp
 extern int a; // указали, что будем пользоваться `int a` из `alpha.cpp`
```

Само связывание имен и памяти произойдет на этапе компоновки программы.

Инициализация в смысле C++ - это когда определение и объявление объединяют с присваиванием начального значения;

```
{
    int a = 8;
}
```

Вот такое:

```
{    
    int a;
    a=8;
}
```

Будет инициализацией в смысле практики программирования (самая первая запись в переменную), но не будет инициализацией в смысле `C++` - это идущие подряд определение и присваивание.

Чтение из неинициализированной переменной - форменное UB. Так писать нельзя, это неправильно.

Comment: *"Определение на всю программу может быть одно и только одно"* Если только оно не `inline`. *"Инициализация - это когда в переменную что-то пишут в первый раз"* Тут спорно. Если понимать "инициализацию" в смысле "присвоение начального значения" - то да, но в C++ у этого слова [есть конкретный смысл](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initialization): инициализацией считается именно задание значения в определении. *"extern, которое как раз говорит компилятору, что переменная объявлена где-то в другой единице трансляции"* `объявлена` -> `определена`

Comment: @HolyBlackCat я старался не углубляться в дебри C++, иначе у меня просто получится трудночитаемый перевод Стандарта.

Comment: _примером чисто объявления переменной будет объявление ее внутри структуры_ non-static data member это не переменная (variable)

Comment: @user397155 - как я могу улучшить свой ответ?

Comment: Декларация может не давать информации о выделении памяти. Могут быть объявления связывающие имя и с неполным типом. Сформулировать ответ в двух строках трудно, лучше всё же почитать соответствующий стандарт. В стандартах разных годов и местоположение и сами формулировки существенно отличаются.

Comment: @gbg , копаюсь сейчас в стандарте тк возник такой же вопрос как и у автора. Здесь, кажется, неточность у Вас:  _примером чисто объявления идентификатора будет объявление его внутри структуры_ . С++20 стандарта у меня нет, так что пользуюсь черновиком [N4868 от 2020-10-18](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2020/n4868.pdf). Там в 6.2 Declarations and definitions пункт (2.20) есть Ваш пример и там он помечен как _defines non-static data member_.  То есть это, похоже, все же определение, а не объявление (для меня это тоже неочевидно, честно говоря)

Comment: @tr1ang1e Хорошо бы сравнить с другими версиями стандарта, может быть, это опечатка, и должно быть declares.

Comment: @gbg У меня, к сожалению, нет оригиналов стандартов. Но в [черновике](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/n4659.pdf) к 17 то же самое. И еще я думаю, что это не опечатка, потому что прямо перед примером есть комментарий: _All but one of the following are definitions_. И тот самый единственный, который не definition, прописан: `struct S { static int y; };  // declares static data member y`

Comment: @tr1ang1e, да, все верно. Если хотите, отредактируйте ответ, либо это сделаю я, когда у меня будет время. Я и так знал, что лезть в это крючкотворство со стандартом чревато ошибками, вот оно и повылазило.

Comment: @gbg , постарался максимально органично исправить. Если не понравится, исправьте мое исправление :) С уважением!

Comment: Я бы еще добавил описание того, почему самый очевидный пример является неправильным

Comment: Сделал, должно быть хорошо

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/129323/discussion-between-gbg-and-tr1ang1e).